# cannot control height w/ percentage in CSS menu

Tags: css, menu, responsive-design, height, percentage

I created a CSS menu w/ submenus, using pixel values for dimensions. Now, that I see how stupid of an idea that was, I tried to convert all pixel values into percentages using the formular `(size / context) * 100` to make the menu responsive.

The original version looked like this:
[image]

After converting everything into percentage values I end up with this:
http://jsfiddle.net/5CK9n/

The main reason is that I am still using px to specefy the height of nav ul li. Whenever I try to specify that height in percent, top menu points (nav ul li) don't change their size at all, and when hovering over one of them to bring out the submenu (nav ul li ul), the top menu point grows in height all over the place.

Could anyone tell me what might be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the css that makes that happen is:

```
nav > ul > li.hasSubMenu:hover + li {
/* this-> */    margin-left: 25%;   
    }
```

And this:

```
nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
/* and this below */
        top: -100%;
        left: 100%;
    }
```

Remove the `top`, `left` and `margin-left` values. See: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/razvannemes/yEc4K/).

Second of all, use `media-queries` to make your navigation responsive. Using just percentages is not effective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I set the top and margin in order to have the submenu comeout next to the main menu point. However, since these are nested ul-tags, the expanding submenu causes the weird hight behavior, right? So I guess I'd have to take the submenu ul out of the main ul.
My main concern, however, is actually the font - I now can control the height (after setting the containing ul display to inline-block), but the font is always either too big or too small. I need to read more into font scaling...